# How change saturation in some part of image?

Tags: ios, image, swift, core-graphics

I have UIImageView with image and some points(CGPOint value). Than I can create path like this

```
var mutablePath = CGPathCreateMutable()
    var point1 = patternImageView.someFeature.rightPoints.objectAtIndex(1).CGPointValue()
    CGPathMoveToPoint(mutablePath, nil, point1.x, point1.y)
    point1 = patternImageView.someFeature.rightPoints.objectAtIndex(2).CGPointValue()
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(mutablePath, nil, point1.x, point1.y)
    point1 = patternImageView.someFeature.rightPoints.objectAtIndex(3).CGPointValue()
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(mutablePath, nil, point1.x, point1.y)
    point1 = patternImageView.someFeature.rightPoints.objectAtIndex(4).CGPointValue()
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(mutablePath, nil, point1.x, point1.y)
    CGPathCloseSubpath(mutablePath)
    var pathForRight:CGPathRef = mutablePath
```

Than I can create rect with all points from path like this

```
var rectRight = CGPathGetBoundingBox(pathForRight)
```

or I can add to array as NSValue

```
var arrayRect = NSMutableArray()
    arrayRect.addObject(NSValue(CGRect: CGPathGetBoundingBox(pathForRight)))
```

Is it possible change saturation of all pixels in rect "rectRight" or change saturation of image in some rect?

Comment: how apply CiFilter only for some rect on image?

Comment: CIFilter includes masking.

Comment: Or, extract a rectangle of the image, apply CIFilter, and put it back again.